# time-point data of two raters

Tags: r, time-series, point, reliability

My data consists of two raters interpreting one specific phenomenon to occur at different points in time. I have two questions:

1) What do I call these data? "Time-series data" seems too general and usually refers to metric data changing continuously over time (while I have just points of data along the time line). Under "time-point data" I don't find problems of the kinds described in question (2).

2) What **indices for interrater reliability** can I use - preferably in R? (If an index requires defining how much offset is tolerated, that could be 0.120 seconds.)

**example data (in seconds)**

rater1:

```
    181.23  
    181.566 
    181.986 
    182.784 
    183.204 
    191.352 
    193.956 
    195.426 
    197.568 
    197.82  
    198.576 
    202.02  
    205.8   
    206.136 
    208.53  
    209.034 
    216.216 
    220.08  
    220.584 
    230.706 
    238.266 
    238.518 
    239.442 
    241.5   
    241.836 
    244.398
```

rater2:

```
    181.902 
    182.784 
    183.204 
    193.956 
    195.384 
    197.694 
    197.82  
    198.576 
    199.5   
    202.146 
    205.8   
    206.136 
    208.53  
    216.258 
    219.576 
    220.542 
    222.096 
    222.558 
    226.002 
    228.312 
    229.11  
    230.244 
    230.496 
    230.832 
    231.504 
    232.554 
    238.266 
    238.518 
    238.602 
    238.938 
    241.5   
    241.836 
    244.272
```

Comment: Perhaps spatio-temporal data? http://www.jstatsoft.org/v51/i07/paper

Comment: To me, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Roman, there is indeed a section very relevant to my question in this paper - that's a good place to start.

Comment: You might be right, Pascal. Any thought of where to ask this question? thanks!

Comment: Here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r?